# How to monitor the progress of multiple sql files

Tags: mysql

I want to monitor the progress while importing multiple mysql dump files. I am using below script;

```
ls -1 *.sql | awk '{ print "source",$0 }' | mysql --batch -u {username} -p {dbname}
```

After a little research I have found mysql 'pv' command but I don't know how to use it with this script.